# Google Maps, how to show distance and travel time in the map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I have used the directions service to render a route on Google Maps. I managed to show the distance and travel time on a marker via the response object which contains the data. **But how do I show the information on hover on the blue polylines?**

For example: [image: valid html]

I have been unable to find this feature in the documentation, but my customer is saying he had this feature in his old website (which is offline, not available anymore).

Is this feature still available in Google Maps? And if so, where are the docs located for this particular feature? Is there another another solution?

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749439/how-to-get-coordinates-in-polyline-using-google-map/62749984#62749984

Comment: Use infowindow in google map

Comment: Hey man, even though I don't need this anymore that indeed is what I was looking for at that time! You can make an answer out of it if you like.