# How to get coordinates in polyline using google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I tried to create a polyline in google Maps. It's created and polyline also working fine. but I need when to click polyline to get coordinates. My Scenario(I have three markers in google map.so, three markers used to connect the polyline markerA connect to markerB connect to markerC. when I click polyline in between markerA and makrerB. I need that two markers latitude and longitude). How to achieve this scenario.

**My Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:5,
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var goldenGatePosition = [{lat: 11.0168,lng: 76.9558},{lat: 11.6643,lng: 78.1460},{lat:11.2189,lng:78.1674}];
for(let i=0;i<goldenGatePosition.length;i++){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: goldenGatePosition[i],
            map: map,
            title: 'Golden Gate Bridge'
            });
}
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path:goldenGatePosition,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2
});
flightPath.setMap(map);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var codeStr=''
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function(event) {
  infowindow.setContent("content");
//         var pathArr = flightPath.getPath()
//         for (var i = 0; i < pathArr.length; i++){
//     codeStr = '{lat: ' + pathArr.getAt(i).lat() + ', lng: ' + pathArr.getAt(i).lng() + '}' ;
//     console.log(codeStr)
  

// };
console.log(event.latLng)
var length = this.getLength();
                                        var mid = Math.round( length / 2 );
                                        var pos = this.getAt( mid );
console.log(pos)
        // infowindow.position = event.latLng;
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.open(map);
    });
}  
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCHmYOxkvd4u3rbHqalUSlGOa-b173lygA&callback=myMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Google Map**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way:

1. include the google maps geometry library.
2. use the [poly namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly) [`isLocationOnEdge`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly.isLocationOnEdge) method to detect which segment of the polyline the click was on. Output the two end coordinates of that segment.

> **isLocationOnEdge(point, poly[, tolerance])**
> Parameters: 
> **point:**  LatLng
> **poly:**  Polygon|Polyline
> **tolerance:**  number optional
> **Return Value:**  boolean
> Computes whether the given point lies on or near to a polyline, or the edge of a polygon, within a specified tolerance. Returns true when the difference between the latitude and longitude of the supplied point, and the closest point on the edge, is less than the tolerance. The tolerance defaults to 10-9 degrees.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function(event) {
  // make polyline for each segment of the input line
  for (var i = 0; i < this.getPath().getLength() - 1; i++) {
    var segmentPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [this.getPath().getAt(i), this.getPath().getAt(i + 1)]
    });
    // check to see if the clicked point is along that segment
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(event.latLng, segmentPolyline,10e-3)) {
      // output the segment number and endpoints in the InfoWindow
      var content = "segment "+i+"<br>";
      content += "start of segment=" + segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(0).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
      content += "end of segment=" + segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(1).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
      infowindow.setContent(content);
      infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
      infowindow.open(map);
    }
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yckL4thb/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#googleMap {
  height: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<div id="googleMap"></div>

<script>
  function myMap() {
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
      zoom: 5,
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    var goldenGatePosition = [{
      lat: 11.0168,
      lng: 76.9558
    }, {
      lat: 11.6643,
      lng: 78.1460
    }, {
      lat: 11.2189,
      lng: 78.1674
    }];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (let i = 0; i < goldenGatePosition.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: goldenGatePosition[i],
        map: map,
        title: 'Golden Gate Bridge'
      });
      bounds.extend(goldenGatePosition[i]);
    }
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: goldenGatePosition,
      strokeColor: "#0000FF",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var codeStr = ''
    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath, 'click', function(event) {
      // make polyline for each segment of the input line
      for (var i = 0; i < this.getPath().getLength() - 1; i++) {
        var segmentPolyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: [this.getPath().getAt(i), this.getPath().getAt(i + 1)]
        });
        // check to see if the clicked point is along that segment
        if (google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(event.latLng, segmentPolyline, 10e-3)) {
          // output the segment number and endpoints in the InfoWindow
          var content = "segment " + i + "<br>";
          content += "start of segment=" + segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(0).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
          content += "end of segment=" + segmentPolyline.getPath().getAt(1).toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
          infowindow.setContent(content);
          infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
          infowindow.open(map);
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=myMap"></script>
```